# Strange behaviour when trying to assign tags to instantiated unity UI game objects

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, tags, instantiation

When I call functions LikeFrame1(),LikeFrame2(),LikeFrame3() once (That is, click the button that call the function it for the first time) a random tag is assigned to the instantiated gameobject (The tag is coming from the other functions where I am doing the same thing, LikeFrame1(),LikeFrame2(),LikeFrame3() respectively)
When I click the button to call it a second time it will assign the proper tag.

I have tried to change where I call assigning the new tag in the function

Here is script with my functions that instantiate the Gameobject and assign the tags:

```
    public class InventoryCreateButton : MonoBehaviour
  {
    public Button Button;

    public void AddItemz1()
    {

        Button go = Instantiate(Button, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), 
        Quaternion.identity) as Button;
        Button.tag = "poop";
        go.transform.parent = 
        GameObject.Find("ButtonListContent1").transform;
        Debug.Log("AddItemz1");

     }

    public void AddItemz2()
    {
        Button go = Instantiate(Button, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), 
        Quaternion.identity) as Button;
        Button.tag = "poop2";
        go.transform.parent = 
         GameObject.Find("ButtonListContent1").transform;
            Debug.Log("AddItemz2");

    }
```

I call them from this script like so:

```
    public class ChooseFrame : MonoBehaviour
    {

    public GameObject currentInterObj = null;

    public InteractionObject currentInterObjScript = null;

    public Inventory inventory;

    public InventoryCreateButton inventorycreateButton;

    public InventoryButtonGetImage inventoryButtonGetImage;

    public void LikeFrame1()
    {
        currentInterObj = frame1;
        if (currentInterObj && _soundOn1)
        {
            inventorycreateButton.AddItemz1();
            _soundOn1 = false;
            Debug.Log(_soundOn1);

        }
        else
        {
            SoundOn1(); //method that can turn the sound on
            _soundOn1 = true;
            Debug.Log(_soundOn1);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void SoundOn1()
    {

        Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("poop"));

    }

   public void LikeFrame2()
    {
        currentInterObj = frame2;
        if (currentInterObj && _soundOn2)
        {
            inventorycreateButton.AddItemz2();
            _soundOn2 = false;
            Debug.Log(_soundOn2);

        }
        else
        {
            SoundOn2(); //method that can turn the sound on
            _soundOn2 = true;
            Debug.Log(_soundOn2);
        }
     }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void SoundOn2()
    {

        Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("poop2"));

    }


    public void LikeFrame3()
    {
        currentInterObj = frame3;
        if (currentInterObj && _soundOn3)
        {
            inventorycreateButton.AddItemz3();
            _soundOn3 = false;
        }
        else
        {
            SoundOn3(); //method that can turn the sound on
            _soundOn3 = true;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void SoundOn3()
    {
        Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("poop3"));
    }
```

No error message and I would expect that the proper tag would be assigned to my instantiated gameobject upon calling the function the first time, not the second time.

Comment: Instead of saying "Button.tag" try "go.tag" and let us know.

Comment: Doesn't `Button.tag = ...` throw an error? it looks like you assigning a value to static property of class `Button` but I don't think it has one

Comment: go.tag is working perfectly. Thank you so much! Do you have an explanation as to why Button.tag was causing me problems?

Comment: @corbinyo Two things: (1) You have `Button` which is a class (UnityEngine.UI.Button) and `Button` which is a property in the code you're writing. This is ambiguous under most situations which is why it is HEAVILY recommended that all variables begin with a lowercase letter (`button`). It may not be ambiguous here because you haven't imported that class with a `using` statement, but it remains ambiguous in context. (2) `Button` is a prefab. When you modify the prefab it *is not the instantiated clone.*

Comment: Thanks! i will make sure to make my naming convention so